# 64 bit hexadecimal AS Date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, hex, data-conversion

I am loading a Qlikview CalData PGO XML file into a SQL table.

Dates in this XML are stored as a 64 bit HEX string and I need to convert it to a date.

How do I do that?

#### Example

`40e58f2c4153d0f9` should be converted to `18/11/2020 09:11:29`

I have seen some sample code within qlikview, which is

```
daystart(date($(HEX64CONVERT(ToBeDeleted))))
```

Comment: It looks like this is explored on the Qlikview forums ([1](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Management/How-to-convert-date-format-from-strange-to-normal/m-p/349980/highlight/true), [2](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Documents/Converting-64-bit-hexadecimal-PGO-dates-to-decimal/ta-p/1494028)). Could you poke around there to refine your question a bit? Certainly asking how to go HexString->(Big)Integer->DateTime could be an answerable platform-specific question - but it's not immediately apparent to me that your sample values follow that convention.

Comment: I have a method to convert this in Qlikview, I need to convert this in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This value is encrypted by QlikView to prevent you from tampering with the value.

> Some fields in the generated XML file i.e. "LastUsed", are encrypted
> for security reasons, thus cannot be converted into readable dates
> using date() conversion. The generated XML files should be used for
> troubleshooting only.

https://community.qlik.com/t5/Support-Knowledge-Base/Reading-PGO-contents-and-CAL-assignments-PGO-to-XML/ta-p/1710604?_ga=2.160240829.1496857553.1606312645-1955769053.1606312645

Presumably this is part of how they track and enforce their sofware licensing agreements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work for you (though you'd have to switch from seconds to milliseconds if your dates are more granular than seconds):

```
SELECT dateadd(s, convert(bigint, convert(varbinary(64), '0x40e58f2c4153d0f9', 1)) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

(I have to verify this solution still when I'm in front of a computer and will update accordingly.)

Comment: It gives me an Arithmetic overflow error

Comment: @mouliin Same, that's because DATEADD() function only accepts INT, not BIGINT. Once I find an alternate way to accomplish that part, I'll update my answer.